# Can't figure out how to use Room TypeConverter

Tags: android-room

I am receiving this response from api. How can I write the TypeConverter for it?. I am using Moshi converter for the api.

```
data class WeatherResponse(
    val current: CurrentWeather,
    val country: String
)
```

```
data class CurrentWeather(
    val cloud: Int,
    val condition: WeatherCondition,
    val feelslike_c: Double
)
```

```
data class WeatherCondition(
    val icon: String,
    val text: String
)
```

Answer (score 0):

First for there to even be a need for a TYpeConverter you will need an `@Entity` annotated class. Such a class, at the minimum MUST have a primary key defined.

Typically, this is a single field(column in database terminolugy), that will be unique, that is annotated with `@PrimaryKey` annotation.

- a Primary Key can consist of multiple columns, in which case the `primaryKeys` parameter can be used.

So for example you could have:-

```
@Entity
data class WeatherResponseEntity(
    @PrimaryKey
    val weatherResponseRowId: Long?=null,
    val weatherResponse: WeatherResponse
)
```

- This is telling Room that you will have a table named WeatherResponseEntity which will consists of 2 columns.

  - One column will be named weatherResponseRowId, the column will have a type of INTEGER (that is a 64 bit signed integer value can be stored in the up to 8 bytes).
  - the other column will be named weatherResponse. Room does not know/understand how a WeatherResponse object will be stored (should it be a boolean value, a string, a byte array/stream .... ). So it needs clarification in the way of a **TypeConverter** (in fact 2).

The job of TypeConverters is to convert a value that is not a string, real/decimal number, integer or byte array/stream into and from one of those 4 types.

- it is probably not practical to implement an method to convert a Java/Kotlin object into a single number. So those two types can be dismissed.

Typically a JSON String representation is used and thus most type converters use JSON libraries to convert such an object into a String and vice-versa.

So to define a TypeConverter for a field that cannot be directly stored. You need to

1. Define a function that will convert the object in question (a WeatherResponse) to, for JSON such a Moshi, a String.
2. Define a function that will convert the String into the object in question
3. Annotate the pair with the `@TypeConverter` annotation (note the singular)
4. Tell Room where to find the converters by using a `@TypeConverters` annotation with appropriate cope (coding this at the @Database level (i.e. just before the `@Database` annotation give the largest scope)). NOTE that the `value` parameter is used to specify class(es) where the TypeConverters are located.

As an example but NOT attempting to delve into how to use the Moshi library you could have:-

```
class TypeConvertersForRoom {
    @TypeConverter
    fun convertFromObjectToString(objectToConvert: WeatherResponse): String {
        return "whatever"
    }
    @TypeConverter
    fun convertFromStringToObject(moshiString: String): WeatherResponse {
        return WeatherResponse(country = "xxx", current = CurrentWeather(99,
            WeatherCondition("icon","none"), feelslike_c = 1.2345678
        ))
    }
}
```

- This, as is stands would convert passed WeatherResponse into the string ***whatever*** and Room would happily store ***whatever*** in the database.
- Again, as it stands, this would return a WeatherReaponse where the country is xxx and the embedded CurrentWeather would always have a cloud of 99 and so on

As can be seen that covers the first 3 of the 4 steps. The 4th step could be along the lines of:-

```
@TypeConverters(value = [TypeConvertersForRoom::class])
@Database(entities = [WeatherResponseEntity::class], exportSchema = false, version = 1)
abstract class TheDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
    // ....
}
```

Now instead of, when compiling the project, encountering the:-

```
Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. You can consider adding a type converter for it.
```

The compile will work although in the above instance it does warn (as would be expected):-

```
Parameter 'objectToConvert' is never used
Parameter 'moshiString' is never used
```

All that is required is refer to the Moshi documentation in regards to how to utilise the library(ies) for the WeatherResponse class.